# how to implement a tripple relation with TypeORM

Tags: typescript, typeorm

i have 3 entities which i want to combine together into 1 mapping table:

- recipe
- ingredient
- unit

i want to combine these 3 entities via a mapping table, which is nothing special in SQL. But when it comes to typeORM, it gets a bit tricky. It is no problem to only combine recipe and ingredient with a ManyToMany relation and the JoinTable annotaion and put the ownership to the recipe entity. This would create a simple mapping table with the id of recipe and the id of ingredient. But i am a little bit stuck how i can also bring in the unit id into this JoinTable. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Maybe a bit more background to the unit: each ingredient basically has a defaultUnit, but it could be that for a specific ingredient-to-recipe relation, another units gets chosen. That's the reason why the additional relation would come in handy. But maybe this is also a wrong SQL design and could be handled differently.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i should have read the docs a bit more, before asking that question here :) if anyone will be stuck on a problem like that, here is how to handle that with typeORM:

https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties